# Close window after save editform with Drop off library

Tags: javascript, custom-form, content-organizer, postback

I have a problem with closing my explorer window from the SharePoint 2010 listitem editform.

I am opening a new explorer window from Outlook. In this window I open the editform from the dropofflibrary with a specific list item.
Now when the user saves the item the window needs to close. (and return to Outlook)

I attempted to use the "source" querystring to reroute to a custom page with a close window javascript. This works if the user presses Cancel, but if Save is pressed the drop off library redirects to a routingmessage page and the source querystring is ignored.
If I do not use a dropofflibrary it works fine. but it needs to work for a dropofflibrary :-(

I attempted to add a content editor webpart to the edit page and manipulate the button.onclick with javascript by adding a window.close after the save event. It closes the window, but the new valeus ar not saved :-(

The event used by the save button is :

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_b21a7767_d050_487a_93f4_2ad6a3e023dc$ctl00$toolBarTbltop$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", true, true))
```

This even has an actionurl parameter. But if I use that I get a message "Page has been changed. Please refresh."

And if I make a copy of the edit form in SPD I lose my contenttype selection on the edit form.

Please help.